# Cant install magento 2 on xampp server

Tags: php, magento, xampp, magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 and run it on XAMPP server.

I have installed XAMPP and Apache and I've downloaded Magento 2 and extracted the file in `htdocs`.

But when I type http://localhost/magento in the browser I get this:

[image: folder]

I think I should have the Magento setup page not this page.

And when I click on it the Magento folder I get this error:

> Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory."

So what is the problem here? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you run the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starting your magento, you need move files form magento2-2.3.5-pl to MAGENTO directory. (1 level UP)

Then you need install composer (https://getcomposer.org/).

And run terminal from magento directory and use command "composer install". This command will install additional libraries that are needed to run the engine

Answer (score 0):

seems you have not downloaded magento with official website 
there are 2 ways to install magento 2
1) downloading from magento website which i have discribed here http://this-adarsh.epizy.com/installation-of-magento-2/

2) via composer steps are given below

stap 1 : install composer

stap 2 : create database for magento installation

step 3 : get magento 2 marketplace key

step 4 : Create a new Composer project using

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition` (if community edition)

or

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition` ( if enterprise edition)
step 5: after successful creation of project run

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

(change your parameter like database name etc.)

you can find more at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

Let me know if you need anything else

Have a good day!