# Magento2 throws install error: 'Interface 'Laminas\\EventManager\\ListenerAggregateInterface' not found'

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to install Magento2 on a aws ec2 factory(t2.medium) running Ubuntu 18.04.
 I am following the installation from here: https://magenticians.com/install-magento-on-aws/#2
I have install every dependency needed for Magento2 like:

> sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php7.3-mysql php7.3-dom php7.3-simplexml php7.3-curl php7.3-intl php7.3-xsl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-zip php7.3-xml composer

I have installed php7.3:
*PHP 7.3.19-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2020 07:48:30) ( NTS )*

I cloned the code here:

> cd /var/www/html
> git clone https://github.com/Magento/Magento2.git

I also changed permissions for the folder:

> change permission:
> chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/Magento2/
> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/Magento2/var/
> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/Magento2/pub/
> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/Magento2/app/etc
> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/Magento2/generated
> sudo service apache2 restart

When I access it in the browser I get http 500 error:
If I look in the /var/log/apache2/error.log I see:

**[php7:error] [pid 9296] [client 79.112.0.14:61776] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Laminas\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface' not found in /var/www/html/Magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Mvc/Bootstrap/InitParamListener.php on line 32**

Any ideas what might be wrong?
thanks

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies via composer? [See here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html#instgde-prereq-compose-install)

Comment: Hm, I followed installation from here: https://magenticians.com/install-magento-on-aws/#2 which seems to be different than your link

Comment: They are slightly different as the title suggests it is installing Magento in AWS, however the missing command is `composer install` from within the Magento directory... that is a step in the article you sent, and the command you have not run yet according to your question details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant install magento 2 on xampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978940/cant-install-magento-2-on-xampp-server)